# How to call a void method in java using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

If I call a method using reflection, the only way I can get it to work properly without throwing a null pointer exception is by returning an int value in the method I'm calling.

For example, the method I want to call:

```
public int setScore(int n)
{
this.score = n;
return 1;
}
```

The way I call it:

```
Method setScore = myClass.getMethod("setScore", new Class<?>[]{int.class});
Object returnValue = setScore.invoke(builder, new Object[]{theScore});
```

Changing the return type to void and calling it seems to always throw a null pointer exception. Do I need to change how I am approaching things for void methods?

Thanks

Comment: I'd think you'd just not store a return value...?

Comment: see this link if it helps http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you show us where the `NullPointerException` is thrown? This codes works correctly:

```
public void setScore(int n)
{
    this.score = n;
}
```

Note that I simplified your code a bit using varargs:

```
Method setScore = builder.getClass().getMethod("setScore", int.class);
Object returnValue = setScore.invoke(builder, theScore);
```

Obviously in this case `returnValue` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If your method no longer returns anything, don't assign the result of invoking it:

```
setScore.invoke(builder, new Object[]{theScore});
```

That alone *won't be it*, though: The only reason I can see for you getting a `NullPointerException` would be if you'd tried to use that variable you assigned the result to (`returnValue`) later, since [`invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) returns `null` if the method's return type is `void`.